# Where might a newbie programmer begin with game development?

Tags: software-engineering, flash

I just started picking up programming and I'd love to learn the ins and outs of game development so if anyone could tell me where to begin I'd really appreciate it alot. I'm interested in flash games in particular for now.

I have googled it up and such but I'm honestly lost what with so much related to the subject so a pointer in the right direction would be immensely helpful. As such any site or resource for the subject would be great.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't the site. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) to see what kinds of questions to ask here. If you read the FAQ, you'll find a [where to get started link](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/how-do-i-make-games-a-path-to-game-development-r892) that should be pretty helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider [GameMaker: Studio](http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker/studio) if you plan on starting with simple 2D games. It is designed to be easy to get started with.
my favorite engine is [Unity](http://unity3d.com/). It is used primarily for 3D games, and has the most intuitive interface I've seen.

However, if you would like to completely code the game, and don't feel a need for a graphical interface, you might want to consider the [Slick2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) library for Java, or [LOVE](http://love2d.org) for Lua.